# How to force a MapView to cover all space on ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I need to show a map view to cover all spaces on the screen. I have added constrains as follow:

First I added this:

[image]

But it didn't work. Then I tried suggested constrains or tick Width and Height in above picture but still I have 2cm empty space on iPhone 6 as you can see in following image:

[image]

Comment: in your add new constraints  remove the lowest red line & add  a new veritically  red line in side the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note your size class is **Compact Width and Compact height**

[image]

That is for 3.5,4,4.7-inch in **landscape**

You should choose **any any**

Then add constraints like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck constrain to margins and then add the constrains again (0,0,0,0).

Answer (score 2):

Your size class is wCompact hCompact.

1. Change it to wAny hAny to get the desired output.
2. Opt to uncheck Constrain to margins option and add 0,0,0,0 Spacing to nearest neighbour
3. Do not fix its height or width els it would remain constant irrespective of iphone screen size .
   U can also refer this link for more appropriate auto Layout concept.http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1
   Hope it helps.. Happy Coding..:)

Answer (score 1):

You should do Leading, Trailing, Top, and Bottom to superview. Do this by control dragging from the MapView to the view. Just make sure that you have MapView taking up the entire view controller in the storyboard when you apply these constraints. Or, do it programmatically.